# Is there a plugin-log plugin?

Tags: plugins

Is there a plugin that logs my usage of plugins on the blog? (when I downloaded a new plugin.  When I activated/deactivated it and so on) ?

Comment: That's a nice question, I like the idea of such a service. I think this would be even something useful to have in core actually.

Comment: Thanks Hakre!  please update here if you'd get to do something :)  Cheers, Tal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have searched fairly extensively, and have not found such a plugin.  The best recommendation I could make is to use the [WordPress File Monitor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-file-monitor/) plugin.  This will at least let you know when a new plugin is installed. Really, you should be using it regardless - it's a great plugin to use as part of an overall security strategy.

Comment: Thanks.  I like that plugin too (although on the last time I worked with it - it didn't work)